# React router dom repeating basename

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

i'm using hashrouter, but when i set the base name, that occours:

**http://localhost:3000/admin/#/admin/dashboard**

i want:

**http://localhost:3000/admin/#/dashboard**

how can i disable the reapeating admin after #?

```
function App() {
  return (
    <>
        <Router basename="/admin">
          <SessionProvider>
            <Switch>
              <Route path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
              <Route path="/users" component={Users} />
            </Switch>
          </SessionProvider>
        </Router>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Where are you generating the paths to link to? Please edit your post to include all relevant code in a [mcve]. We can't help diagnose or debug code we can't see.

Comment: i put my routes

Comment: And what of the links or navigation actions going to these routes?

Comment: but its occours when i start the aplication too, i dont need to click in any link =[

Comment: Oh, I see... the hash router's `basename` prop is everything *after* the `/#/`. Perhaps you just need a `"homepage": "."` entry in the package.json file?